# Insert dynamic .rst block in sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx

I am creating a sphinx documentation where I'm often re-using the same block of text/code, e.g. below:

```
.. raw:: html

   <div class="class-xyz">
     <video playsinline="" autoplay="" loop="" muted="" style="width:100%;">
      <source src="https://url.myvideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
     </video>
   </div>
```

Is there a way to avoid writing the whole thing every time - and instead including such a block of `rst` content in a function or similar that I can include, while parsing the dynamic part (the URL) as a functional input?

Comment: What did you try? Did you [search the Sphinx docs for "include"](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/search.html?q=include)? You can find the `include` directive listed in the [reStructuredText Primer](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/basics.html#directives) with a link to its usage in [docutils](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#include).

Comment: I did review the `include` directive, however it seems like this directive does not support the parsing of an input (such as the URL). The `include` seems useful for generic insertion of `rst` files where no modification of the content of the `rst` file is required - where in this case I'd like to parse an input to the included content. Maybe it's something obvious, but I did try to review various parts of the docs with no luck.

Comment: I cannot reproduce what you describe with the example provided. You must edit your question with sufficient information. Also describe what you mean by "parsing the dynamic part". That said, there are a [couple Sphinx extensions that makes embedding videos easier](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/develop.html#extensions), and you could modify one to your preferences.